# Call custom event log method from selected methods after they finish on windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, logging

I have a windows forms application with a custom event logging that stores on a table in my database some data.
What i do to log this events it's something like this:

```
methodA()
{
    //some code
    performLog(someParameters);
}

performLog(someParameters)
{
   //save on the database
}
```

The problem is that i need to call the method `performLog` on many methods in my windows application so my question is that if there is some better way to achieve this.
Something like this?

```
[PerformLog]
methodA()
{
   //some code
}
```

Where `PerformLog` makes the performLog method after the methodA has finished.
Oviously i will call `performLog` method manually in some special cases.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at "Aspect Oriented Programming".

Answer (score 0):

To be able to perform a generic logging in all my applications, I've generated a simple static class called EventLogger that implements a static Method 
SendMessage( ... ) with the parameters I need for my logging
and a static event,  LogNewEntry

The Static method SendMessage launches the static event with the given data.

This allows me to implement the event handler of the LogNewEntry event just once (usually in program.cs for Winforms or App.xaml.cs in WPF) the event handler performs the logging on a text file or a database or whatever I need and throughout my program, whenever I want to Log something I just call
EventLogger.SendMessage(...) passing the needed data.

If you think you want to see the code I can post a sample to show you.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but my approach was to make something that would left the event code "outside" the method code, that's why in my example i ask if something like `[PerformLog]` can be made

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with outside the method code, I've seen your Attribute but for what I know about attributes they are used to give information to methods executed against a class (the easiest to recall are those for serialization) I'm not sure an Attribute is the right place to perform log operations, but of course it's just because I have never had that kind of need...

Comment: I mean that in some cases i would need to add this `PerformLog` method in the middle of some code, other cases at the end.. and i was looking for a nice way to make those calls

Comment: Sorry to answer so late, maybe you already solved, but if you want to see a generic logger implemented you can read this
http://blogs.dotnetwork.it/sabrina/en/blog/implemetare-un-sistema-di-log-generico-per-le-nostre-applicazioni/
It is in English :o)